# How trigger observable value emission after adding an item to an array of observables using RXJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an observable array in my service:

```
gearItems$: Observable<GearItem[]>;
```

This array gets instantiated in the constructor for testing purposes:

```
constructor() 
  {
    this.gearItems$ = of([
      { ID: 1, name: 'T-shirt', price: 10, sizes: [
        { size: Size.L, available: false , color: 'warn' }, ,
      ], inStock: true, images: [
        { ID: "1", name: "image1", size: 12, type: "type", url: "../../../assets/IMG_5585.JPG" },
        { ID: "123", name: "image2", size: 12, type: "type", url: "../../../assets/IMG_5904.JPG" }
      ]...)
  }
```

I need to update/add a single item in that array and trigger a new value emission:

```
updateGearItem(gearItem: GearItem): Observable<GearItem>{
    return this.gearItems$.pipe(
      flatMap((gearItems: GearItem[]) => {
        return gearItems.filter(gI => gI.ID !== gearItem.ID);
      })
    )
  }

  createGearItem(gearItem: GearItem): Observable<any>{
    // create HTTP request to the backend to create a new item
    return this.gearItems$.pipe(
      map(gearItems => {
        gearItems.push(gearItem)        
        return gearItems;
      })
    )       
  }
```

However I am not able to do so. In my component on ngOnInit I have a subscription listening for the `gearItems$: Observable<GearItem[]>;` observable array:

```
ngOnInit() {    
    this.merchandiseService.fetchAllGearItems().subscribe(
      (gearItems: GearItem[]) => this.gearItems = gearItems
    );
  }
```

But whenever I try to add or update items in the observable array nothing happens. What am I missing here?

Comment: where is the subject underlying the observable?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. But are you asking where is the subject that would be responsible for emitting new values? Not sure if its relevant but I tried changing the Observable<GearItem[]> to Subject<GearItem> and then inside of the createGearItem map function I tried doing gearItems$.next() but it didnt do anything.

Comment: observables are just a definition of how to handle a stream of events, they need to have some event source, usually a subject but not always.  You just declare gearItems$ and don't ever show where it gets created / initialized.

Comment: I have updated my questions with the code from the constructor to show where the gearItems$ array is initialized

Answer (score 0):

For emitting value changes you can use a BehaviorSubject and Observable. BehaviorSubject emits new value(e.g getting data from http.get) every time next method called. Subscription used for handling application lifecycle events and before component destruction we should unsubscribe.

```
private itemsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<GearItem[]>(null);
items: Observable<GearItem[]>;
subscribtion: Subscription;

gearItems$: Observable<GearItem[]>;

constructor() 
{
    this.items = this.itemsSubject.asObservable();
    ... [rest of code] ...
}

createGearItem(gearItem: GearItem): Observable<any>{
    // create HTTP request to the backend to create a new item
    return this.items.pipe(
      map(gearItems => {
        this.itemsSubject.next(gearItems); // this line emits new value
        return gearItems;
      })
    )       
}

ngOnInit() {    
    this.subscribtion = this.items.subscribe(
      (gearItems: GearItem[]) => gearItems$ = gearItems;
    );
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscribtion.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in a simple form.

`addItem` will fetch what's currently in `BehaviorSubject` and append a new item as side effect. Please note the 1st `first()` is to make sure we only take the latest value from BehaviorSubject or it'll keep emitting because there's a .next in the the succeeding `tap()`. The last first() is to complete the observable

```
const items = new BehaviorSubject([])
const addItem =
  (item) => items.pipe(
    first(),
    tap(arr => items.next([...arr, item])),
    first(),
  )
items.subscribe(console.log)
addItem('a').subscribe()
addItem('b').subscribe()
addItem('c').subscribe()
```